# How can we create a distributed array for specific number of workers (cores) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have a question: 
How can we create a distributed array for specific number of workers in MATLAB? In other words, if we have 4 workers(cores) in our computer and we would like to designate just 3 workers to process a distributed array, how can we do that. I used the existing commands in this way:

a=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
b=codistributed(a);

Unfortunately, this instruction use all four workers!

Please, any idea how to solve this problem?

Kind regards
Ammar

Answer (score 0):

`parfor` uses `n` available workers called by `parpool(n)`

you can set instead `parpool(3)`

Matlab doesn't have parallel constructs like OpenMP or MPI, in which case you can set one worker to do a job and three others to do another job.

Comment: Hi Marouen, I would like to thank you for this answer. Yes, as you said if  used parpool(3) I can use just 3 workers, however, I need the fourth one for different job. Please, if there is any other way to solve the problem. Regards.

Comment: really there isn't. you can start another matlab instance for the 4th job.

Comment: Dear Marouen, Thank you very much for clarify that for me.

Comment: Please, Marouen, Do you have any idea to solve my second question ! It is in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571057/how-can-we-implement-a-parallel-pipeline-using-3-workers-in-one-computer-in-matl